# Javascript substring acting strangely

Tags: javascript, substring

I have created a function to turn a 24 hour string aka "0800" or "2330" into minutes.  Sometimes the strings will drop leading zeros so I need to account for this.

It works BUT to get the minute component I try get the last two characters of the string which, one would assume, would be this:

```
var timeString = "800"; //Can be "0800"
timeString.substring(timeString.length - 2, 2)
```

Which, if your string is "800" (leading zero dropped) then it would be the equivalent to

```
timeString.substring(3 - 2, 2)
```

However this returns nothing what so ever.  I only get "00" (what I'm looking for) if I use the following code:

```
timeString.substring(timeString.length, 2)
```

To me this code is wrong but it works, somehow?

Can anyone explain why? Have I misunderstood how this function is meant to work?

Comment: "0800" is the result or the input for your function?

Comment: `string.substring(from, to)` perhaps you mean `string.substr(start,length)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter in the substring method isn't the number of characters you want it is the index you want to go to. So right now you are going from substring(3-2, 2), index 2 to index 2, which gives you no characters.

Change it to:

```
timeString.substring(timeString.length-2, timeString.length)
```

Comment: AHHHHH! I mis-read the docs.  In almost every other language substring works by `substring(position, length);` not `from` and to` - Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here the second parameter is the index of the to character.
What you are looking for is the substr function instead.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are doing is, getting the text from index 2 to 2, that's obviously is an empty string. You really want to use String.prototype.slice here. It allows you to use negative parameters as a way to index from the end (basically string-length - index). Specifying no second parameter will extract everything till the end of the string.

```
timeString.slice(-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've confused the `substring()` function with the `substr()` function.  `substring()`'s second parameter is the ending index of your substring, while `substr()`'s second parameter is the length of your string.

Try substituting `substr()` for `substring()`...